# Como criar uma nova biblioteca no C++

Tags: c++

Gostaria de saber como para criar uma nova biblioteca  em `C++`. se alguém poder dar um exemplo, pode ser um exemplo generalizado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dois tipos de bibliotecas serão explicados: estáticas e compartilhadas. Abaixo um exemplo com a criação de ambas em linha de comando no **Linux**.

**Biblioteca estática:** Usada na compilação

**main.cpp**

```
#include "libprint.h"

int main(){

   //Função guardada numa biblioteca estática
   print_ola("Rafael");
}
```

**libprint.h (Cabeçalho da biblioteca estática)** - 
é bom criar um arquivo de cabeçalho para sua biblioteca.

```
#ifndef LIBPRINT_H
#define LIBPRINT_H

   void print_ola(const char *);

#endif
```

**printola.cpp (Código da sua biblioteca estática)**

```
#include "libprint.h"
#include <iostream>

void print_ola(const char *nome){

   std::cout << "Olá, " <<  nome << "!" << std::endl;
}
```

**Passos para criação da biblioteca estática:**

Gere o código objeto do printola.cpp: `g++ -c printola.cpp`. Agora empacote o código objeto em forma de biblioteca:

`ar crv libprintola.a printola.o`

Pronto! Já tens uma biblioteca estática chamada **libprintola.a**! (mais códigos objetos podem ser inseridas em uma só biblioteca ex: `ar crv libprintola.a printola.o printalgo.o etc`).

Compilação e execução:

`g++ main.cpp -o programa libprintola.a`

`./programa`

Saida: Olá, Rafael!

**Bibliotecas Compartilhadas:** - (com os mesmos arquivos anteriores!)

`g++ -c -fpic printola.cpp` cria o código objeto objeto que pode ser utilizado como compartilhada.

`g++ -shared -o libprintola.so printola.o` cria sua biblioteca compartilhada chamada **libprintola.so**!

Testando: `g++ -L. -Wl,-rpath=. -Wall -o programa main.cpp -lprintola`

Que deverá exibir o mesmo resultado. (mas cuidado! cada uma funciona de forma distinta!)